# How to sort local date and reformat it in Element ui table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm using table from Element UI

I get local date in format like this as String:

```
let date = this.startDateAt.toLocaleString('ru-Ru')
```

output is :

`28.09.2021, 19:01:00`

**How to sort elements in table by it's local date?**

I want reformat date to get output in table like this:

28 сен 2021 19:01:00

```
<el-table-column
          prop="local_date"
          label="Дата"
          width="132"
          sortable
        />
```

So the main goal is to sort local date and reformat it

Comment: Do you have a format function already?  If so, I can show you how to use it.

Comment: But I don't know what should I format to make it work for sorting in element ui table